# Static random number generator losing seed for global variable

Tags: c++, random, static, static-methods, static-members

I wanted to make an easy way to grab a random number, however, gen, the random number generator seems to lose its seed across functions. If you run this example multiple times, you will see that the first random number generated is random each run, while the second is not. What is the cause of this?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Random.hpp"
class Global
{
public:
    Global()
    {
        Random::seed();
        std::cout << "\n" << Random::getRandom(-10, 10);//random
    }
    void Global::doStuff()
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << Random::getRandom(-10, 10);//not random
    }
};
Global globalInstance;

int main()
{
    globalInstance.doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Random.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <random>
class Random
{
public:

    static void seed();
    static int getRandom(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive);

private:
    static std::default_random_engine gen;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ints;

};
```

Random.cpp

```
#include "Random.hpp"
#include <time.h>
std::default_random_engine Random::gen;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> Random::ints;
void Random::seed()
{
    gen.seed(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
}
int Random::getRandom(int minInclusive, int maxInclusive)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type range(minInclusive, maxInclusive);
    ints.param(range);
    return ints(gen);
}
```

Comment: You made gen a static member, it's behaving like a static member, which is different from a static non-member.

Comment: Please edit your post, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: My mistake, I went for a minimal example when I should have given a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I fixed it a while ago, and the example is simple and repeatable. What do I do when no one is responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed appears to be dependent on the statically-scoped objects in `random.cpp` getting instantiated before the statically-scoped objects in `main.cpp`.

This is undefined behavior. The C++ standard does not guarantee the relative instantiation order of statically-scoped objects from different translation units.

What appears to be happening, is that your implementation instantiates `main.cpp`'s static object first, which sets the random seed in the object that's defined in the `random.cpp` translation unit. This, in itself, comprises undefined behavior, but this operation seemingly survives without crashing.

After `main.cpp`'s static object gets instantiated, `random.cpp`'s static objects get instantiated, thus resetting them to use the default seed value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to accomplish what I was striving for, which is a global access point to Random::getRandom(min, max); that does not fail like this?

Comment: You can take advantage of the fact that function-level static objects get initialized the first time function scope is entered. Wrap all your objects into a single class, declare it static in a function that returns a pointer to its internal static object, and invoke it.